# How to do series operator in pandas?

Tags: pandas, operator-keyword, series

Now I set up a series.

```
data = {'MSFT': 0.059090993,'JNJ': 0.013080726, 'MMM': 0.01361722}
weights = pd.Series(data)
```

Also, I have a data frame saved in csv.

```
Date        MSFT  JNJ   MMM
2019-09-01  0.1   0.02  -0.01
2019-09-02  0.03  0.1  -0.03
2019-09-03  -0.05 0.04  0.02
```

Then,

```
returns = pd.read_csv('stock_returns.csv')
means_returns = returns.mean()
returns = np.sum(mean_returns*weights) *252
```

However, I got an error "cannot join with no overlapping index names"

How can I solve the error?

Comment: Which lines raises that error?

Comment: Hi rafaelc, sorry for confusion. The last line raises the error. returns = np.sum(mean_returns*weights) *252

Comment: The error is clear. You have data frames with no overlapping index names. Investigate your indexes - they have to be the same! e.g. if you have date as index in one, and numbers as index in the other, you can't multiiply these dfs

Comment: Your code works fine with the provided data.